# How do I add a timer to my C++ project?

Tags: .net, c++, winforms, timer, c++-cli

I have my C++ project, and I want an event to start 40 seconds after my form is loaded. I know there is a timer in C++, but it only shows intervals.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008. I'm creating a Windows Form Application. Do you guys know what function I have to use?

Comment: Well, use a timer. Set it for 40s. Start it when the app starts. When timer event fires, destroy the timer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup the timer using a 40 seconds interval and remove the timer when it's first triggered.

Comment: But the interval of the timer its not in seconds. My program runs here System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)

Comment: @Giuseppe the interval's in milliseconds, just multiply your seconds by 1000. ie. for 40 seconds: `40 * 1000`.

Comment: @ AusCBloke: i just got my last question, if im running all my code in that interval, but i want that something happen in that specific time. What do i do ?. 
PD.Sorry bout my grammar, im not an english-speaker.

Comment: @Giuseppe, at the bottom of the link I posted, there's an example for C++ with a function `static void TimerEventProcessor`. When the timer is "raised", that function will be run. Also look in the function `Main` where the `EventHandler` is set up for the timer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the .NET [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx#Y0)? Why doesn't it work for you? That link provides examples (assuming that's what you're talking about) of setting it up and then after it's gone off you can just dispose of it so your event doesn't start multiple times.

**EDIT**: The interval is in milliseconds, so just multiply your seconds amount by 1000. ie for 40 seconds, `40 * 1000 = 40000`.

**EDIT2**: As per your other comment, at the bottom of the link I provided is an example for C++. The `TimerEventProcessor` is set as an `EventHandler` for the timer in `Main` and will be run when the the timer is "raised" (Visual Studio might already set that up for you when you add a `Timer` control to the form). Since you only want the timer to run once and you don't need the other functionality it provides, I would simply choose to use a thread as I previously suggested:

You could also simply have another thread, which calls `sleep` to wait for 40 seconds, and then starts your "event."

Comment: @Giuseppe, if you find the questions you ask on SO are answered, mark them as such; ie. Sylence's or my answer depending on which one you considered answered your question in the most helpful way.